# Roll-up summary field - limit on the records to be summarised

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

Is there any limit on the number of records that can be summed up or in general summarised? I do not see any constraint on this matter in salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5) but I still need to be really sure that there is not any limitation.

Comment: I have never gone through any such limits. However, Sesforce does say that, we should not have more than 10000 children records related to a parent.

Comment: It is probably a bad design decision to have very large number of child records associated with a single parent. Any time someone is editing one of the children, that also locks the parent for edit. This can lead to lots of row-lock errors. So, if you're still in the design stages, think hard about whether or not you want to have so many children. If you do hit a limit, you might be able to use DLRS (https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) in batch mode to work around the limit.

Comment: Another consideration is that if you start having records with thousands upon thousands of children, that's when you start running into issues with _index skew_ (i.e. the distribution of parent Ids in child records is not very uniform, and heavily _skewed_ so that a few parent Ids are much more likely than the rest). Index skew can make a particular index virtually useless (giving you non-selective query errors).

Comment: Can you add an answer my question in a separate thread so that I can select the best answer? :) thanks.

Comment: @DerekF Not to hijack Cuban coffee's thread, but do you have any references on index skew? That's a new one on me and I'm curious.

Comment: @DavidReed Took me a while, but I was writing an answer based on index skew. It's finished now. Hope it's a good read for ya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, no, there is not a limit I am aware of on the number of records that can be part of a roll-up summary.

Practically speaking, however, there is a limit.

There may be more than a few reasons why there is a practical limit, but the one I'll focus on is *Index Skew*.

**tl;dr:**
Just because you can doesn't mean that you should. Having a whack-ton of child records all related to a single parent is a recipe for index skew, which can start making your queries fail due to query cost (and query selectivity in general). Databases like more uniformly distributed data, and a "good" system design will take this into account.

### Understanding Index Skew

There are a few different parts that you'll need to understand to understand index skew. Broadly speaking, you need to know a bit about probability (and distributions), and a bit about how indexes work in DBMSs (DataBase Management Systems).

#### Probability and Skew

There are many different types of probability distributions, but the one we're most concerned with here is the *uniform distribution*. If we have a set of integers 1 - 10, a uniform distribution means that the chance you'll see a 4 is exactly the same as the chance you'll see a 10, is exactly the same as the chance you'll see a 3, etc... Each number has a 10% chance of appearing.

We can apply this concept to more than just numbers. Say you have some `OpportunityLineItem` records (OLI from here on), each related to some `Opportunity`. If we have 100 OLIs, and between them we encounter 10 unique Opportunity Ids, then a perfectly uniform distribution of OLIs on Opportunities would mean each Opportunity would have 10 OLIs.

In reality, data is never this uniform. There will be some variance. Some Opportunities may only have 5 OLIs, others may have 20, a rare outlier might only have one. This is generally not an issue until you start to see extreme deviations from the average.

As an anecdote from my company's org, after we sell a customer some service, we track the services we sell our customers as `Asset` records related to the customer's `Account` record. On average, we have about *5-20 Assets* that we are actively billing each customer. When we went to integrate data from another billing system into Salesforce, the difference in the structure of the data led to us having hundreds to a few thousand Assets on an individual account. The very worst offender had something like *89,300* Assets related to a single Account.

That right there is skew, a very extreme skew, deviating by a couple thousand standard deviations (or sigma). Particle physics generally requires a signal with a deviation of 6 sigma to claim a discovery. In this case, we've completely blown that out of the water.

*Skew is a significant deviation from the average*.

#### Databases and Indexes

Databases store a lot of data, and we generally don't want to wait for a long time to figure out which records were created on a specific day.

One of the tools a DBMS can use to optimize query performance is to use an index. A database index is a lot like the index in the back of a cookbook. You're interested in, say, making a pizza. The index tells you what pages you can find recipes for pizza on, which saves you the trouble of starting from the first page, and looking through every recipe until you find one for pizza.

In a database, indices point to locations in memory or disk where your record is located. This can be extremely helpful, because accessing data from disk is slow (both in terms of latency, nanoseconds for cache and tens to hundreds of milliseconds for disk, and bandwith).

The other benefit of indices is that it reduces the number of records that you need to process other parts of the WHERE clause on. `WHERE Moves__c LIKE '%Jagger%'` is still an expensive operation, but if you only need to evaluate that on 100 records, the time it'll take to evaluate that won't be as bad as if you needed to evaluate that on 10,000 records.

#### Index skew (pulling concepts together)

So, let's say that you have a couple of Opportunities with 9000 OLIs each.

If your average OLI count is around 10, you have some very severe index skew. *On average, if you take a random OLI, this one Opportunity will appear much more often than most others*. Salesforce will know where to find the records that you need, *but using the index may no longer be faster than just scanning all of the OLI records in your org*. It may be faster for Salesforce to do this "Tablescan", and use other criteria in your WHERE clause to filter out records to reduce the working set that other filters need to be applied to.

Tablescans are best avoided if possible. It takes time to compute, and Salesforce needs to make sure that one customer on a pod doesn't adversely affect performance for other customers on that same pod. This is where query cost, and query selectivity come into play.

If you're familiar with the query plan tool in the dev console (help -> preferences -> enable query plan, which will give you a "Query Plan" button in the query editor tab), you can use that to see how much of a burden your query is on Salesforce's resources. Plan costs closer to 0 are better, and if your best plan cost is over 1.0, then your query is non-selective.

Index skew hurts your query cost in two ways.

- Makes it less favorable to use the index to optimize the query
- Makes it so that you're returning a larger volume of records

I'm not sure if record volume directly contributes to query cost (it wouldn't surprise me if it did), but Salesforce also uses % of total records to determine query selectivity. If you only have 30,000 OLIs, and one Opportunity has 9,000 of them, then if you happen to query that one Opportunity with 9,000 OLIs *and any other Opportunity*, then you automatically fail even the most permissive of Salesforce's selectivity thresholds (30% of records when total records is < 1 million, and using a standard indexed field).

### Conclusion

So, while there is technically not a limit to the number of child records you can have related to a single parent, the real world has other considerations that need to be made.

In traditional DBMS, we can try to fix skew by "sharding" data into different databases, but that's not really an option in Salesforce. We can split data across different SObjects (or even just different records of the same SObject), but that would make any code that needed to use that data more complex.